# Code that compiled fine in MSVC2013 seems to confuse MSVC2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I'm trying to migrate my development environment from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015, and I'm running into a weird issue with one of my projects. The compiler somehow seems to think I'm trying to reference a deleted move constructor while I'm actually trying to use a regular constructor to throw an instance of a class.

I'm writing a thin wrapper around libcurls HTTP capabilities. Here's one example of a compilation error I'm getting. I'm getting two more of these in similar but different parts of the code.

```
1>e:\code\win32\contentwatcher\contentwatcher\http_client.cpp(18): error C2248: 'http::curl_error::curl_error': cannot access private member declared in class 'http::curl_error'
1>  e:\code\win32\contentwatcher\contentwatcher\http_client.hpp(19): note: see declaration of 'http::curl_error::curl_error'
1>  e:\code\win32\contentwatcher\contentwatcher\http_client.hpp(16): note: see declaration of 'http::curl_error'
```

This is the relevant part of http_client.hpp:

```
namespace http {

class curl_error : public std::runtime_error ////////////////// LINE 16
{
    curl_error(const curl_error &) = default;
    curl_error(curl_error &&) = delete; /////////////////////// LINE 19
    curl_error &operator=(const curl_error &) = delete;
    curl_error &operator=(curl_error &&) = delete;
public:
    curl_error(const char *message, CURLcode cc);
    curl_error(CURLcode cc);
    ~curl_error() = default;
protected:
private:
    CURLcode m_code;
    std::string m_details;
};

class curl_init
{
    curl_init(const curl_init &) = delete;
    curl_init(curl_init &&) = delete;
    curl_init &operator=(const curl_init &) = delete;
    curl_init &operator=(curl_init &&) = delete;
public:
    curl_init(long flags = CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    ~curl_init() = default;
protected:
private:
};

} // namespace http
```

And the relevant part of http_client.cpp where the actual compilation error occurs:

```
http::curl_init::curl_init(long flags)
{
    auto cc = curl_global_init(flags);
    if (cc != CURLE_OK) throw curl_error{ cc }; /////////////// LINE 18
}
```

As you can see I'm just trying to construct a `curl_error` object in order to throw it as an exception. Worked fine in MSVC2013 but 2015 seems to think I'm trying to move-construct it?

I have no idea what's wrong here, or which keywords to Google to solve this... Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C++ language spec, when talking about the `throw` statement, it says:

> Throwing an exception copy-initializes a temporary object, called the exception object.

So the exception object you're throwing needs to be copyable.

Since your copy constructor is private, it is not accessible. You need to make it public and implement it.

Comment: I movied the `curl_error(const curl_error &) = default;` to the public section of the class definition, but it still gives the same error. The class has 2 member variables. As I understand it, a compiler generated copy constructor automatically calls the copy constructor on those member variables, correct?

Comment: @Jehjoa Since the error is specifically mentioning the line with the move constructor, you should try making that public as well.

Comment: Thank you, fixed by making the move constructor public. It's still `default` but it works. The copy constructor is still `private` and `delete`d.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
throw curl_error{ cc };
```

is trying to construct a `curl_error` from another `curl_error`.  So we need the copy constructor.  The code you posted has a private  copy constructor.

You just need to make the copy constructor public.

Comment: The OP has `curl_error(const curl_error &) = default;` in their code.  Also move will not be used as `cc` is an lvalue.

Comment: Just corrected the answer.  I missed the copy c'tor when I first read the code.

Comment: Also, `cc` is a variable of type `CURLcode` which is a `typedef enum`, and not a `curl_error`.

Comment: @Jehjoa You should include that information in the question.